# Is anyone know why the else code part can't hide my colorPicker?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm still new with Swift 4 and i found this on the internet & tried to make this Button to show "something" when the image button is A. But when i clicked the Button again, only its image button changed but the "something" still not hidden. Can someone help ?

I already done with other button that using this animation but the button is showing another button from Library.
But this 1 is different, not showing another button from Library but showing ChromaColorPicker

```
var sizeOff = UIImage(named: "Brush-Size")

var sizeOn = UIImage(named: "Brush-Size-On")
```

============================ somewhere else ======================

```
extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func BrushColourClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.currentImage == ColourOn {
            sender.setImage(ColourOff, for: .normal)
        } else {
            sender.setImage(ColourOn, for: .normal)
        } // Image first set
        configureUI()

    }

    func configureUI() {
        let colorPicker = ChromaColorPicker(frame: CGRect(x: 25.0, y: 410.0, width: 140.0, height: 140.0)) // Position & Size of Color Picker

        ColourButtonCenter = colorPicker.center
        colorPicker.center = BrushColour.center

        colorPicker.delegate = self
        colorPicker.padding = 5.0
        colorPicker.stroke = 3.0
        colorPicker.hexLabel.isHidden = true
        colorPicker.layout()
        view.addSubview(colorPicker)
        colorPicker.alpha = 0

        if BrushColour.currentImage == ColourOn {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
                colorPicker.alpha = 1
                colorPicker.center = self.ColourButtonCenter
            })
        } // Animation show
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
                colorPicker.alpha = 0
                colorPicker.center = self.BrushColour.center
            })
        } // Animation hide
    }
}
```

i dont know if 
`colorPicker.alpha = 0`
is working or not

Comment: You shouldn't hide UI elements using their `alpha` property, you should use the `isHidden` property. Unrelated to your question, but you should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable and function names (`colourButtonCenter`, `brushColourClicked`, `colourOn`, `colourOff`).

Comment: @DávidPásztor There is nothing wrong with using `alpha` instead of `isHidden`. View with `alpha = 0` behaves the same as view with `isHidden = false`.

Comment: still nothing happen after changing to isHidden, i'll try to find the real problem :o

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `configureUI` you're adding a new colour picker to the view, then animating the alpha on it.

So when you're trying to hide the `colorPicker` what's actually happening is that you're adding a new colour picker with `alpha 0` and animating it to `alpha 0` (doing nothing), the previous `colorPicker` will still be visible so it will look as though nothing as changed.

Create a variable for `colorPicker` once and add it to the view, then configure that instance in your `configureUI` function.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'll try to configure the instance inside configureUI